# CSS Color além do tamanho do elemento

Tags: css, css3

Estou montando um layout utilizando o framework [Bulma.io](https://bulma.io/). Até o momento está da seguinte maneira.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha dúvida é:

Como fazer com `CSS` toda a minha `div` lateral ficar pintada? Como na imagem acima, quero pintar o espaço em branco que está riscado de vermelho.

Eis meu `html`.

```
<div class="container is-fluid">
    <div class="columns">
        <aside class="column is-narrow aside hero is-fullheight">
            <div style="width: 200px;">
                <p class="notification is-info"></p>
            </div>
        </aside>
        <div class="column">
            <p class="notification is-warning"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

E o `css` usado para colorir a `div` lateral.

```
.aside {
    display: block;
    background-color: rgb(58, 73, 83);
}
```

Comment: Jovem sem o código fica difícil te responder. Mas com certeza é ajuste de margem! Posta o código ai pq do jeito que está complica...

Comment: @hugocsl postei o código, tem a ver com as margens, mas não queria tirar a margem do elemento, só fazer a cor ir além da margem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que para essa situação o melhor a fazer é usar o `box-shadow`.

A propriedade `box-shadow` não ocupa espaço então ela não interfere nos outros elementos.

Fiz um exemplo para demonstrar melhor. Repare que a linha pontilhada é o limite da `<div>` já a cor cinza é o `box-shadow`, Repare que ele não empurra a `<div>` inferior mais para baixo!

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0;
}
.box {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    outline: 1.5px dashed red;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px silver; /* controle aqui até onde vai a cor */
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    Meu conteúdo
</div>
<div class="box">
    Meu conteúdo
</div>
```

Comment: Excelente, funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado!!

Comment: Dica de ouro :) boa sorte com o projeto!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar no seu código *CSS*, o seguinte comando:

```css
body {
    background: #163c7a; /* ou a cor que você deseja */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Visto que você referiu que o problema é das margens faça o seguinte

```
.aside {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-top:10px;
    display: block;
    background-color: rgb(58, 73, 83);
}
```

Com as alterações acima referidas, você irá ter o espaço na mesma mas irá estar pintado da cor da `div`.

Outra forma é retirando a `margin` como no exemplo acima mas adicionando uma `border-left` com `10px` de width e com a cor que desejar